# How do I get RVM to be recognised in the terminal on my Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm, zsh

I'm trying to get rails setup up on a mac following [this tutorial](http://eddorre.com/posts/rails-ultimate-install-guide-on-os-x-lion-using-rvm-homebrew-and-pow) and a [tutorial on rubysource.com](http://rubysource.com/rails-development-101-rvm/)

I have installed oh-my-zsh and RVM but when I try the command:

> rvm type | head -1

I get zsh: correct 'rvm' to 'rvim' [nyae]?

Which is throwing me because this should display in the terminal:

> rvm is a function

If I choose 'n' I get:

> zsh: command not found: rvm

and if I choose 'y' I get:

> Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal

I'm super new to using a mac (bought it yesterday) and am struggling with getting ruby and rails all set up as I do on my windows system.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have probably forgotten to add the line to your `.zshrc` which loads RVM.

As given at your first link:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

If this line is in `~/.zshrc`, then RVM should be loaded when you open a new shell. Otherwise, you'd have to run

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Whenever you wanted to use RVM.

Comment: thats done the trick! Thankyou very much! I was adding that line to .bash_profile.